# exercise 9.3 in How To Think Like A Computer Scientist

Tags: python, string, list, search

Exercise 9.3. Write a function named avoids that takes a word and a string of forbidden letters,and that returns True if the word doesn’t use any of the forbidden letters.
Modify your program to prompt the user to enter a string of forbidden letters and then print the number of words that don’t contain any of them. Can you find a combination of 5 forbidden letters that excludes the smallest number of words?
got the first part:

```
def avoids(word,forb):
    for letter in forb:
        if letter in word:
        return False
    return True
```

struggling with the second, here's my attempt:

```
fin=open('C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 2.7\words.txt','r')

def no_contain():
   forb=raw_input('enter the forbidden letters')
   tot=0
   ct=0
   for line in fin:
       word=line.strip()
       for word in fin:
           tot+=1
           for letter in forb:
               if letter in word:
               ct+=1
       return tot-ct
```

getting some funny answers. Also, when should you use the `ct=0...ct+=1` technique instead of `ct=ct+1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def avoids(word, forb):
    for letter in forb:
        if letter in word:
            return False
    return True

def no_contain(fin):
    forb = raw_input('enter the forbidden letters: ')
    count = 0
    for word in fin:
        if avoids(word.strip(), forb):
            count += 1
    return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fin = open('words.txt', 'r')
    print no_contain(fin)
```

when to use `ct = ct + 1` instead of `ct = ct + 1`?

Actually, they are the same thing in python, all evaluate the result of `ct + 1` and then bound it to `ct`, because `int` class in python is immutable.

Comment: noooice! it worked. How do I become a python demon in a short period of time?

Comment: I am also a novice to python, except I have some C experience before.So the style of my program is more like C, not object oriented; if python is your first language, borrow a classic book to learn python systematic, then look at other good programmer's program, learn how they think, how they implement, and try some project your self, you can't become a specialist in programming in a short period of time, there is a classic [article](http://norvig.com/21-days.html) by Peter Norvig. Hope be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

'''
Exercise 9.3. Write a function named avoids that takes a word and a string of forbidden letters,
and that returns True if the word doesn’t use any of the forbidden letters.

Modify your program to prompt the user to enter a string of forbidden letters and then print the
number of words that don’t contain any of them. Can you find a combination of 5 forbidden letters
that excludes the smallest number of words?
'''

```
def avoids(strg, word):
    for letter in strg:
        if letter in word:
            return False;
    return True;

fin = open('words.txt')
def No_Contain(strg):
    count_word_no_contain = 0;
    for line in fin:
        result = avoids(strg, line.strip());
        if(result == True):
            count_word_no_contain += 1;
            print(line.strip());
    return count_word_no_contain;

print(avoids("HUY STRAUSS", "LION"));
strg = "lion king";
print("The number of words doesn’t have the letters of the string", strg, "is: ", No_Contain(strg));
```

'''
RESULT:
The number of words doesn’t have the letters of the string lion king is:  9971
'''

Answer (score 0):

```
forbidden=input("Enter the forbidden characters: ")  
fin=open("words.txt")  

def avoids():    
    for letter in fin:    # Searches the letter in the file
        word=letter.strip()    
        if forbidden not in word:    #If forbidden char is not in the file
            print(word)    
print(avoids())
```